# Date automation down columns

Tags: google-sheets, date

I know how to get Google Spreadsheets to automate dates down a column. Write a date, left click on the crosshair in the bottom right hand corner, drag down and let go.

The thing I'm hoping to do though is have, say, ten (or any given amount) rows down a column of today's date, then ten of tomorrow's date, and so on down indefinitely. It's for inputting sales data.

Comment: The "indefinitely" part wouldn't work :) but you could write a script to do something like that depending on exactly what you want. For instance you could have a script that add rows for the next ten days w 10 rows each whenever you clicked on it. If that's something you want to try I can probably make an example.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the first row is used for column headers, you can enter

```
=arrayformula(date(2015,11,8) + floor((row(A2:A)-2)/10))
```

into cell A2, and get the list of dates with each repeated 10 times. This list will fill the entire first column; if more rows are added later, they will be automatically filled as well.

A formula can't add new rows to a spreadsheet (for that one would need a script), but if someone is manually entering sales data, they may as well add rows when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter and one less function but would require formatting of the output:

```
=42316+int(0.1*(row()-x))
```

Where `42316` is the date serial number and `x` is the number of the row in which the formula is entered.

Would require copying down to suit but I see you accept that as automation.

[INT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093490)
[ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)